# Mismatch of size of /var/run/utmp and `struct utmp` in Linux built with GLIBC 2.38 (Y2k38 fix)

Tags: linux, busybox, glibc, 64bit

I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10.24), which is a **32bit** system, and it is using GLibc-2.38 to fix Y2k38.

The rootfs is built from buildroot rel.2023-aug with Y2k38 fix. (built with  `-D_TIME_BITS=64 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE`).

There are `getty` and `login` built from `busybox-1.36.1` in the buildroot.

Now I found strange things when I tried to read the `/var/run/utmp` with following codes (also built with  `-D_TIME_BITS=64 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utmp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    struct utmp ut;

    printf("XXXXXXXXX sizeof utmp: %ld\n", sizeof(ut));
    fp = fopen("/var/run/utmp", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening UTMP file");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fread(&ut, sizeof(struct utmp), 1, fp) == 1) {
        if (ut.ut_type == USER_PROCESS) {
            printf("Login Name: %s\n", ut.ut_user);
            printf("Login Time: %s", ctime(&ut.ut_tv.tv_sec));
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

When root is logged in and run the code, it showed,

```
# /tmp/utmpread
XXXXXXXXX sizeof utmp: 400
```

But the size of `/var/run/utmp` is 384.

```
# stat /var/run/utmp
  File: /var/run/utmp
  Size: 384             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fh/15d  Inode: 8           Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 1970-01-01 01:14:24.270002128 +0000
Modify: 1970-01-01 00:03:12.000000000 +0000
Change: 1970-01-01 01:12:47.210002082 +0000
```

So based on my tests, it seemed that `struct utmp` is already built as 64bit of `timeval_t`, and the `login` and `getty` also report its size is 400Bytes.
But the size of `/var/run/utmp` is still 384 Bytes, which is using 32bit `timeval_t`.

I don't know why there is the mismatch (the code reports size of `struct utmp` is 400, but the file generated from `struct utmp` is 384), is it from the GLIBC or from the `busybox`?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to read `/var/run/utmp` correctly by referring to `who.c` in busybox.

```
    struct utmp *ut;

    setutent();
    while ((ut = getutent()) != NULL) {
        if (ut->ut_type == USER_PROCESS) {
            if (strcmp(ut->ut_user, "root") == 0) {
                printf("root logged in\n");
            }
        }
    }

    endutent();
...
```

But the question is still valid, why the sizes are different?

Comment: I don't have a way to confirm this, and my last C programming was really decades ago, but when you run `struct utmp *ut` you are only declaring space for a particular structure, so when you say `sizeof(ut)` you getting the size of the declared data structure. You need to run a function to "populate" that structure with values, which you are now doing in you answer code. My assumption is that now that the structure has data populated, it size has changed and that seems normal. Any allocated space for char arrays are now zero terminated strs and that would affect the size of the struct reprted.

Comment: That is to say, if the structure has room for a 60 char string, and you only use 40, that would reduce the reported size. Learn to use dbg (the debugger) and how to inspect these things (-;  .... ALSO, depending on OS, the struct may be "zeroed-out" where all elements are completely populated with NUL, and as you run the init/population function, that will use real live data, which (likely) will report a different size.

Comment: I did another test with the same codes, but without those 64bit options for compiling. This time, the size of struct utmp is 384, the same size as the file. And by dumping the /var/run/utmp, I found there are more trailing `0`, I am not sure if there is any other `zeroed-out` happened when the struct utmp is fully written to disk file.

Comment: 1) So you now have matching sizes reported. Case closed? 2) Did you have a problem you were trying to fix besides "sizes don't match"? If yes, then post a new question after reading [mcve]. 3) Do you know about std C lang string termination with `NUL` (`0`)? 4) `gdb` is debugger installed with the `gcc` compiler, but as you're doing busybox, there may be a different compiler/debugger you have to use. Find a tutorial about using that debugger and dig in (-;! 5) Good luck.

Comment: No no, my answer is just a way (correct way) to read `/var/run/utmp`, but it still did NOT answer the original question on the mismatch of `struct utmp` and file of `/var/run/utmp`. So it still needs more investigation. I can build gdb for this embedded system, but I am not sure if gdb can help in debugging the GLIBC code (I think the mismatch come from the GLIBC), which calls `write` behind `endutent()`.

Comment: 1) There is likely another, smaller `dbg` tool you can build for your project. 2) If you're using `yocto` as your platform there is definitely a specialist support forum you can find where you may get better help. ELSE find the specialist forum for the build tool you **are** using. 3) if you post a new question (Q), review [mcve] and be clear in your Q how this mismatch in size is a problem your project. Is some other part of your code failing? Why do you think the size mismatch is a problem?  ...

Comment: 4) I think I have read about GLIBC problems with busybox etc, but I have no meaningful experience to offer a fix.  5) if you have switched to using 32bit OS/build be sure to highlight that. Good luck.

Comment: The codes in my answer is correct to read `/run/utmp`, BUT there is another way to read `/run/utmp` like `while (fread(&ut, sizeof(struct utmp), 1, fp) == 1)`, this code is failed for the mismatch of size of `struct utmp` and the size of `/run/utmp`, resulting in failure of reading `/run/utmp`. I am really NOT sure what is the root cause of this mismatch, I checked the header file, it is good, and I also tried using `strace` to check the writing of `/run/utmp`, it showed 384Bytes are written. So it needs to figure out why GLIBC writes 384B not 400B of the whole `struct utmp`.

Comment: I am out of ideas. I am not sure you understand my points in my comments. Consider reviewing each sentence and see if that sparks a new thought. Posting a new questions seems like your best bet, but read about [mcve] and make your question so readers can copy/paste yourr code into their local environment and experience the same problems. Also be sure to define your busybox envirnoment and 32 vx 64bits. Good luck.

Comment: I just updated the original question by “BOLD"ing the 32bit, it also mentioned the kernel version, busybox version and glibc version. I hope this is clear to describe and helpful to understand the situation. :-)